# How to change the DOM of popup.html?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to edit the DOM of Popup.html in my Google Chrome extension. I have tried to access it in popup.js using:

```
document.getElementById("Example").value = "Hello";
```

But this seems to do nothing. Am I supposed to be accessing this from a different script i.e. background script or via a different method?

My extension runs fine and popup.js file runs as expected all except the line above.

Here is my popup.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      button {
        height: 30px;
        width: 100px;
        outline: none;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="Example">N/A</button>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.2/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: The background script runs in a separate hidden background page so you don't need it at all for this task. You also don't need a content script for that. Simply use the standard `<script src="popup.js"></script>` in your popup.html before the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I managed tosolve this problem by changing

```
document.getElementById("Example").value = "Hello";
```

to

```
document.getElementById("Example").innerHTML = "Hello";
```